# Visio Web Access web part not available in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, visio-services

Soon I'm going to be migrating a SharePoint site from on premises to SharePoint Online and one of the pieces that I'm moving is a page with the Visio Web Access web part.  When I tried to see how it works in SharePoint Online by inserting into a page I noticed that it was not available under "Business Data".

[image: Business Data Part]

I checked to make sure that the enterprise site collection and site features were enabled and they both were.  I also verified that I have the enterprise licenses required (E3) to run the Visio Services.

How can I make the Visio Web Access web part available to add to pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution from someone who was trying to [enable the Excel Web Access web part](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office_online_support_blog/2015/12/10/cannot-add-an-excel-web-access-web-part-in-sharepoint-online/).  The solution is to enable custom scripting capabilities.

1. Go to Admin -> SharePoint -> Settings
2. Find the "Custom Script" section
3. Switch these to "Allow users..." (By default the options are set to prevent users from running custom scripts on personal sites and self-service created sites)
4. Wait up to 24 hours (according to Microsoft) and then the option should show again

The "Custom Script" section evidently [toggles a lot of different web parts](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sridhara/2015/04/02/the-new-custom-script-no-script-feature/).